# Produce resulting jars with different builds/shaded code

Tags: maven

We're refactoring our app to allow for multiple database support, mainly MySQL (current) and MongoDB (in dev). For MySQL we have to shade in tomcat jdbc pool code, and for Mongo we shade in the java driver. I need to produce two builds - one for MySQL, one for Mongo.

I'm trying to find a way to do this with maven - only shade tomcat-jdbc or mongo and some internal code needed for that database system. However, I'm not seeing much in the way of multiple builds and have seen several SO answers advising not to use it.

I've also considered separating the database code into different projects entirely - so we can provide the product, and a second jar with either mysql, or mongo code. It's a bit messier for end users, but cleaner for us.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There is a very important rule in maven (or any other dependency management system):

**Different results should always have different coordinates**,

or the other way round:

**Building from the same sourcecode state should always result in the same artifact, regardless of profiles or target systems.**

So, if you want to produce two different results, you need them to have different coordinates. Your two options are:

a) one project creating different classifiers (which is ugly but workable)

b) or create two submodules `myproject-mysql` and `myproject-mongodb` (which in turn shade your main code and the respective db-code) (different artifactIds)

There is nothing against shading to create a complete jar, in your case just create two separate jars, which are fully workable by themselves.